# Log4j migration -Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/FileAppender

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm migrating one of our project from log4j 1 to log4j 2 using log4j-1.2-api.
So I start by removing the log4j1 and place log4j-api, log4j-core and log4j-1.2-api into classpath.
When I run the app service, I got below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/FileAppender
        at org.apache.log4j.builders.BuilderManager.parseAppender(BuilderManager.java:72)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertiesConfiguration.parseAppender(PropertiesConfiguration.java:428)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertiesConfiguration.parseLogger(PropertiesConfiguration.java:406)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertiesConfiguration.parseLoggers(PropertiesConfiguration.java:351)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertiesConfiguration.doConfigure(PropertiesConfiguration.java:304)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertiesConfiguration.doConfigure(PropertiesConfiguration.java:93)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.Log4j1Configuration.initialize(Log4j1Configuration.java:60)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:293)
        ...
```

From [migration docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html), I've impression that the FileAppender is supported.

```
Supported Appenders include: AsyncAppender, ConsoleAppender, DailyRollingFileAppender, FileAppender, NullAppender, RewriteAppender (limited), RollingFileAppender, SyslogAppender.
```

If the FileAppender is supported, why does it throw exception?

Comment: Which version of Log4j 2.x are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.17.1 of  log4j-api, log4j-core and log4j-1.2-api

Comment: someone_smiley Was this resolved?

Comment: @KasumiGunasekara, no, I am trying avoid using the bridge and migrate to log4j2 fully instead

Answer (score 1):

Update Log4j 2.x version as 2.17.2 instead of 2.17.1.

Then for log4j upgrade from 1.x to 2.x can be achieved by removing the log4j 1.x and adding log4j-api, log4j-core and log4j-1.2-api of version 2.17.2.

Comment: The configuration factory in Log4j 1.x bridge does not actually use the `org.apache.log4j.FileAppender`, but replaces it with its Log4j 2.x Core equivalent. The OP's configuration should have worked on 2.17.1.

Comment: The issue in my case was that `org.apache.log4j.FileAppender` was used by another library used in the module. It gave `Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/FileAppender` error, therefore, I checked by upgrading to 2.17.2.